# Added more files than i need

Tags: java, file, iterator

Adding to my ArrayList seems to create more elements than I expected -  after adding the second element, files appear to be duplicated.

```
public void addFileToList(File file) throws IOException {
        if (myList.size() == 0) { //size of my Array
            myList.add(file);
        } else {
            for (ListIterator<File> iterator = myList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    if (!FileUtils.contentEquals(file, iterator.next())) {//filter files
                        iterator.add(file);//add 8 elements 
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    
            Branch br = new Branch("master"); //create Class
            File file1 = new File("/Users/pro/IdeaProjects/MyNewGit/1.txt"); //create Files
            File file2 = new File("/Users/pro/IdeaProjects/MyNewGit/3.txt");
            File file3 = new File("/Users/pro/IdeaProjects/MyNewGit/4.txt");
            File file4 = new File("/Users/pro/IdeaProjects/MyNewGit/6.txt");
    
    
    
            br.addFileToList(file1); //add Files 
            br.addFileToList(file2);
            br.addFileToList(file3);
            br.addFileToList(file4);
        }
        
    }
```

I added 4 files but 8 appeared:
[Contents of ArrayList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFpJO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is simply wrong:

Let's say your list already contains files a, b and c. And you call your method with file d.

Look at your loop:

```
for (ListIterator<File> iterator = myList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    if (!FileUtils.contentEquals(file, iterator.next())) {//filter files
        iterator.add(file);//add 8 elements 
    }
}
```

It tests if a is different from d. It is, so you add d. Then it checks if b is different from d. It is, so you add d again. Then it checks if c is different from d. It is, so it adds d again.

You need to test if **all** files are different from d. And after the loop, when you know the answer, then you can add the new file.